# SMT solver gives up on seemingly trivial problem

Tags: smt-solvers

I expected CVC5 to produce a proof given the following problem in TPTP format.
Why does CVC5 give up on the TPTP problem, but works just fine on the same problem given in SMT-LIB2?

In human words, the problem says that all values `X` of type `tA` are in the unary relation `rel`. And given some arbitrary value `a` of that type, we want to prove that fulfills `rel`.

```
thf(ty0, type, tA : $tType).
thf(ty1, type, a : tA).
thf(ty3, type, rel : tA > $o).
thf(ax4, axiom, ![X : tA]: (rel @ X)).
thf(goal, conjecture, rel @ a).
```

CVC5 gives the following `unknown` output.

```
unknown
(
; cardinality of $$unsorted is 1
; rep: (as @$$unsorted_0 $$unsorted)
; cardinality of tA is 1
; rep: (as @tA_0 tA)
(define-fun a () tA (as @tA_0 tA))
(define-fun rel ((BOUND_VARIABLE_346 tA)) Bool false)
)
```

However, CVC5 manages to find a proof just fine given the same problem expressed in SMT-LIB2.

```
(set-logic ALL)
(declare-sort A 0)
(declare-const a A)
(declare-fun rel (A) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x A)) (rel x)))
(assert (not (rel a)))
(check-sat)
```

Unfortunately, since SMT-LIB2 doesn't support higher-order logic, I need to use TPTP.
This problem is a minimised version of a more complex problem involving inductive data types, where CVC5 attempts to instantiate the constructors of my inductive data types for some reason.

Comment: I apparently [needed the `--full-saturate-quant` option](https://github.com/cvc5/cvc5/issues/9177#issuecomment-1262362364). For the record, I use CVC5 1.0.2.